# A label ran—typically a company one

Tags: cryptic-clues

> A label ran amidst the small country Bangladesh. (5)

In case you want to know more, here's a rotten hint:

> `zejjvsxqnydcdkmuohmrkxqonydmywcvkcraeocdsyxccvkcr48732cvkcrzednkcrwonkcrlopybonkcrxog`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is:

> BRAND - RAN between BD(Bangladesh) [However, I have hardly seen Bangladesh been referred to as BD. Clarification: the OP says that BD is the abbreviation of Bangladesh. I will take her word for it.]

The Hint:

> Actually, says to Rot 16 which links to another if the OP's puzzles which has the same answer.

Comment: It says to ROT 10.

Comment: Google. **bd** is made for Bangladesh.

Comment: http://www.rot-n.com/

Comment: **Bd** is the abbreviation of Bangladesh, hence "**small** count Bangladesh".

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine It is ROT-10 if you go the other way round.

Comment: take a look here under places: it appears the OP is correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BD

Comment: In wiki: "***Bangladesh, where "BD" is the ISO 3166-1 2-letter country code
.bd, the country top-level domain for Bangladesh.***"

Comment: http://sustainablesources.com/resources/country-abbreviations/